# Speed up Python script's for loop

Tags: python, performance, bash, for-loop

Assuming you got something like this (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541056/pinging-an-ip-range-with-scapy)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

TIMEOUT = 2
conf.verb = 0
for ip in range(0, 256):
    packet = IP(dst="192.168.0." + str(ip), ttl=20)/ICMP()
    reply = sr1(packet, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    if not (reply is None):
         print reply.src, "is online"
    else:
         print "Timeout waiting for %s" % packet[IP].src
```

There is no need to wait for each ping to finish before trying the next host. Could I put the loop interior each time into the background along the lines of the `&` in:

```
for ip in 192.168.0.{0..255}; do 
ping -c 1 $ip &
done
```

Comment: Beside the point, but are you aware that `range(0,255)` ends at  `254`?

Comment: thanks for the typo correction

Comment: You could use the [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) module to do pings concurrently.

Comment: You should use some asynchronous library, or select. 

Also, `reply is not None` looks better than `not (reply is None)`. ;)

Comment: You can actually provide a range of IP addresses to capy, and it will send out accordingly, you can then evaluate the results of sr separately, which would work a lot faster as there should be less I/O blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you should do is change your range to `range(0, 256)` so that it is inclusive of 0-255.

Second, you're looking at Python's threading, which can be somewhat similar to Bash process daemonization at an abstract level.

Import multiprocessing and create a pool:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(20)  # However many you wish to run in parallel
```

So take the ping lookup, which is everything inside of the for loop, and make it a function.

```
def ping(ip):
    packet = IP(dst="192.168.0." + str(ip), ttl=20)/ICMP()
    reply = sr1(packet, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    if not (reply is None):
         print reply.src, "is online"
    else:
         print "Timeout waiting for %s" % packet[IP].src
```

Then in your for loop,

```
for ip in range(0, 256):
    pool.apply_async(ping, (ip,))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

`pool.join()` is what waits for all of your threads to return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `threading` or `multiprocessing` module to run aynchronous/non-blocking IO calls.

Read about hte difference on SO:

[multiprocess or threading in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226584/multiprocess-or-threading-in-python)